# I have an issue with loops

Tags: python

I want the game to loop as long as the answer to the last question is 'yes'. How do i do that? The code is shown below, and it describes a very simplified rock paper scissors game.

```
print("Welcome to rock paper scissors game")
p1 = input("Player 1 what do you choose? r/p/s")
p2 = input("Player 2 what do you choose? r/p/s")
if p1 == "r":
    if p2 == "r":
        print("no one wins. rematch")
    elif p2 == "p":
        print("player 2 wins! Congratulations")
    elif p2 == "s":
        print("player 1 wins! Congratulations")
    else:
        print("error")

if p1 == "p":
    if p2 == "r":
        print("player 1 wins! Congratulations")
    elif p2 == "p":
        print("no one wins. rematch")
    elif p2 == "s":
        print("player 2 wins! Congratulations")
    else:
        print("error")

if p1 == "s":
    if p2 == "r":
        print("player 2 wins! Congratulations")
    elif p2 == "p":
        print("player 1 wins! Congratulations")
    elif p2 == "s":
        print("no one wins. rematch")
    else:
        print("error")

response = input("Do you want to start a new game? yes/no")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exit = ''

while exit != 'yes':
    Your code here!
    .... 
    ....
    exit = input('do you want to exit? (yes/no)')
```

Read about loops for Python

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something called a "do while" statement.

From what I remember in python, there is not a "do" keyword like you could see in other languages.

Here is an alternative:

```
while True:
    # the code you already have

    # set response = input
    if response != "yes":
        break
```